# Mixed-Integer Model Predictive Control using Gekko

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko, mixed-integer-programming

**Problem statement:**

Trying to utilize [GEKKO](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to optimally select the number of appliances within the available capacity while minimizing the energy cost.

**Problem model:**

I cannot post an image but [here](https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?%5Cdpi%7B110%7D%5Cleft%5C%7B%5Cbegin%7Bmatrix%7D&space;%5C%5C%5Cmin&space;%5Csum&space;_%7Bt=1%7D%5E%7B24%7D&space;n&space;x_%7Bi%7D&space;P_%7Bi%7D%5C%5C&space;%5C%5C%5Ctextrm%7Bsubject&space;to:%7D%5C%5C&space;%5C%5C&space;%5Csum&space;_%7Bi=1%7D%5E%7B24%7D&space;C_%7Bi%7D&space;-&space;x_%7Bi%7D&space;=&space;0&space;&space;%5C%5CC_%7Bmin%7D&space;%3C&space;C_%7Bi%7D%3C&space;C_%7Bmax%7D&space;%5C%5Cx_%7Bmin%7D&space;%3C&space;x_%7Bi%7D%3C&space;x_%7Bmax%7D&space;%5C%5Cn_%7Bmin%7D&space;%3C&space;n_%7Bi%7D%3C&space;n_%7Bmax%7D&space;%5C%5C%5Csum_%7Bt=1%7D%5E%7BT%7D&space;%5Ctau_%7Bi%7D%5E%7Bt%7D&space;=&space;I_%7Bi%7D%5Cend%7Bmatrix%7D%5Cright.&space;) is the link to see the formula and also you can copy and paste below to find it visually better:

```
\min \sum _{t=1}^{24} n x_{i} P_{i}
```

subject to:

```
\sum _{i=1}^{24} C_{i} - x_{i} = 0 
C_{min} < C_{i}< C_{max}
x_{min} < x_{i}< x_{max}
n_{min} < n_{i}< n_{max}
\sum_{t=1}^{T} \tau_{i}^{t} = I_{i}
```

where,
***x*** and ***n*** are the state variables representing the assigned power and number of appliances in a station. ***C*** is the capacity,  is the operating state of appliance (the ON/OFF condition) at time slot ***t***, and **I_{i}** is the permissible interval for each appliances (i.e. 5 hrs)

**Work done so far:**

Thanks to post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727310/mpc-with-arx-model-using-gekko/63731362#63731362.) I put the following together:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,23,24)

#initialize variables
cap_low = [55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,68.,68.,68.,68.,\
           55.,55.,68.,68.,68.,68.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.]
cap_upper = [75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,70.,70.,70.,70.,\
             75.,75.,70.,70.,70.,70.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.]
TOU = [0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,\
       50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,0.05,0.05,0.05]

k = 1.1 #Safety factor
CL = m.Param(value=cap_low)
CH = m.Param(value=cap_upper)
TOU = m.Param(value=TOU)

x = m.MV(lb=6, ub=32)
x.STATUS = 1  # allow optimizer to change

n = m.MV(lb=1, ub=10, integer=True)
n.STATUS = 1  # allow optimizer to change

# Controlled Variable
C = m.SV(value=55)
m.Equations([C>=CL, C<=CH])

m.Equation(k*C - n* x == 0)
m.Minimize(TOU*n*x)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve(disp=True,debug=True)

plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,cap_low,'k--')
plt.plot(m.time,cap_upper,'k--')
plt.plot(m.time,C.value,'r-')
plt.ylabel('Demand')
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.step(m.time,x.value,'b:')
plt.ylabel('Load')
plt.xlabel('Time (hr)')
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.step(m.time,n.value,'r:')
plt.ylabel('No. of Appliances')
plt.xlabel('Time (hr)')
plt.show()
```

[image: outcome]

**Outcome**

The above code results in a promising result but there is a lack of last constraint `\sum_{t=1}^{T} \tau_{i}^{t} = I_{i}` for limiting the operation time of each appliances.

**Question:**

This problem seems like a combination of Model Predictive Control (tracking the available load capacity) and a Mixed Integer Linear Programing (multiple appliances with multiple linear operational equations). So the questions are:

1. How can I define the permissible interval for each appliances in above code to limit their operation in a day.
2. What is the best way to integrate MPC and MILP in Gekko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question 2: Switch to the `APOPT` solver to solve `MILP` or `MINLP` problems.

Answer to question 1: Separate `n` into the individual appliance state with:

```py
# decide when to turn on each appliance
na = 20 # number of appliances
a = m.Array(m.MV,na,lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)
for ai in a:
    ai.STATUS = 1
    ai.DCOST = 0

# number of appliances running
n = m.Var(lb=1, ub=5)
m.Equation(n==m.sum(a))
```

[image: new solution]

The bottom subplot shows when the individual appliances are on or off. Limiting the appliance to 5 hours per day is causing problems with convergence:

```py
ax = [m.Intermediate(m.integral(ai)) for ai in a]
for ai in ax:
    # maximum of 5 hours each day
    m.Minimize(1e-4*ax**2)
    m.Equation(ax<=5)
```

Perhaps you could start with this code and try other strategies to improve convergence such as different [APOPT solver options](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) or form of the constraint. Creating a soft constraint (penalize with a financial incentive instead of a hard limit) can also help to improve convergence.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote=True)
m.time = np.linspace(0,23,24)

#initialize variables
cap_low = [55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,68.,68.,68.,68.,\
           55.,55.,68.,68.,68.,68.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.,55.]
cap_upper = [75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,70.,70.,70.,70.,\
             75.,75.,70.,70.,70.,70.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.,75.]
TOU = [0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,\
       50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,50.,0.05,0.05,0.05]

k = 1.1 #Safety factor
CL = m.Param(value=cap_low)
CH = m.Param(value=cap_upper)
TOU = m.Param(value=TOU)

x = m.MV(lb=6, ub=32)
x.STATUS = 1  # allow optimizer to change

# decide when to turn on each appliance
na = 20 # number of appliances
a = m.Array(m.MV,na,lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)
for ai in a:
    ai.STATUS = 1
    ai.DCOST = 0

ax = [m.Intermediate(m.integral(ai)) for ai in a]
for ai in ax:
    # maximum of 5 hours each day
for ai in ax:
    # maximum of 5 hours each day
    m.Minimize(1e-4*ai**2)
    m.Equation(ai<=5)

# number of appliances running
n = m.Var(lb=1, ub=5)
m.Equation(n==m.sum(a))

# Controlled Variable
C = m.SV(value=55)
m.Equations([C>=CL, C<=CH])

m.Equation(k*C - n* x == 0)
m.Minimize(TOU*n*x)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.NODES = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 1

m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 3']

m.solve(disp=True)

plt.subplot(4,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,cap_low,'k--')
plt.plot(m.time,cap_upper,'k--')
plt.plot(m.time,C.value,'r-')
plt.ylabel('Demand')
plt.subplot(4,1,2)
plt.step(m.time,x.value,'b:')
plt.ylabel('Load')
plt.xlabel('Time (hr)')
plt.subplot(4,1,3)
plt.step(m.time,n.value,'r:')
plt.ylabel('No. of Appliances')
plt.subplot(4,1,4)
for ai in a:
    plt.plot(m.time,ai.value)
plt.xlabel('Time (hr)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It is absolutely a beautiful approach but does not address the complete solution, because the number of working appliances is bounded regardless of available capacity. There might be two ways to address this:
1) set the upper bound of `x` to some values relational to the available capacity such as `n = m.Var(lb=1, ub=max(cap_low)/appliance_rating)` where `appliance_rating=7` kW.
2) Running a Monte Carlo sequential optimization to play with `n` and find the maximum possible appliance while reducing the cost.

@Prof. John Hedengren, kindly share your thoughts on my above comments.

Comment: For solution finders surfing stackoverflow you need to change `ax` to `ai` in lines 34 and 35 to make the John's code running.

Comment: @user7250174 - thanks for catching the error. The addition constraints or Monte Carlo approach are promising. Let us know how it works.